# How to convert from normal string to array of JSON Dynamically in TypeScript Angular 8

Tags: json, typescript, angular8

**The below (string) return array of JSON dynamically in shape of (string):**

```
let test = '{ "UserDepartmentName": { "OldValue":"Abc123", "NewValue": "Abc123456"  }, "ModifiedDate": { "OldValue":"5/19/2021 12:37:22 PM", "NewValue": "5/24/2021 4:12:21 PM"  } }'
  }'
console.log(test)
```

**I need to convert this (string) to (array of JSON) to extract the data like below:**

```
{
   "UserDepartmentName":{
      "OldValue":"Abc123",
      "NewValue":"Abc123456"
   },
   "ModifiedDate":{
      "OldValue":"5/19/2021 12:37:22 PM",
      "NewValue":"5/24/2021 4:12:21 PM"
   }
}
```

I used the below technique to do this, but the first value **UserDepartmentName** is not appear:

```
jsonconvert(json) {
 
    const obj = JSON.parse('{ "UserDepartmentName": { "OldValue":"Abc123", "NewValue": "Abc123456"  }, "ModifiedDate": { "OldValue":"5/19/2021 12:37:22 PM", "NewValue": "5/24/2021 4:12:21 PM"  } }');
 
    console.log(json);
 
    for (var i in obj) {
      console.log(obj[i]);
    }
 
  }
```

> ****How to convert the (string) value to (array of JSON) using (TypeScript in Angular 8)?****

**Note:**

- The string data is dynamic and every time it will be changed
- The first value in the string is always changing
- OldValue & NewValue is always there under one of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log `console.log(obj)` you can see that it is being parsed. If I run your code, it actually does log the value of 'UserDepartmentName' - but not the key it self:

```json
{OldValue: "Abc123", NewValue: "Abc123456"}
{OldValue: "5/19/2021 12:37:22 PM", NewValue: "5/24/2021 4:12:21 PM"}
```

If you want to log the key, you can iterate like so:

```json
for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(i + '= ', obj[i]);
}
```